# How to use TextView action on ToolBar

Tags: android, toolbar

I'm using TextView on ToolBar, I want to set this TextView on right and Search View is left

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:anroid="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_search_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" >

    <TextView
        anroid:id="@+id/toolbarTextView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="FILTER"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor" />
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test result" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

When I build, TextView is not appear on right of ToolBar, and it just appear EditText of SearchView.

How to fix the problem? Thank you

Comment: Why trying adding textview and not changing title of Toolbar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED ANSWER**

A SearchView is an options menu item in your Toolbar, and you can't have a custom TextView to the right of it, because custom views are *always* to the left of the options menu items (see [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) documentation).

So, if you want some text to the right of the SearchView, you can just add another menu item like this:

menu/main.xml:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/filter"
        android:title="FILTER"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

layout/activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_search_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test result" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar t = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_search_result);
        setSupportActionBar(t);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.filter) {
            // Do here whatever you want if FILTER is clicked
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This should result in something like this:

[image: Search collapsed]
[image: Search expanded]

**OLD ANSWER**

Try to modify your TextView like this:

```
<TextView
        anroid:id="@+id/toolbarTextView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="FILTER"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor" />
```

The TextView does not appear, because you set `android:visibility="gone"`.

Also, you should use `wrap_content` rather than `match_parent` for the TextView to not cover the title of the Toolbar.

And `android:layout_gravity="right"` causes the TextView to be displayed at the right edge of the Toolbar.

Comment: I have instead of android:layout_gravity="right" and it has appeared, however when seach view expand, TextView is still left

Comment: If you have a SearchView in your Toolbar, then the TextView will always be to the left of it, you can't place it to the right of the SearchView. But you can add another menu item with your desired text to the right of the SearchView, see edited answer.